# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today' | datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Keep getting this error that the package is not being installed. Any Fixes?

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

time_change = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

today_var = datetime.today().date() + time_change
print(today_var)
```

> AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
time_change = timedelta(hours=2)
```

You already imported `datetime.timedelta` as `timedelta` so you can use that.

But you imported `datetime.datetime` as `datetime` so that is why it is saying `'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'`.

Answer (score 0):

This line `import datetime` imports the `datetime` module, but not the `datetime` class:

```
import datetime
attributes = dir(datetime)
print('today' in attributes)
False
```

To access the datetime class, you need to add the line `from datetime import datetime`:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
attributes = dir(datetime)
print('today' in attributes)
True
```

So now you can access `datetime.today()`:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

time_change = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
today_var = datetime.today().date() + time_change
print(today_var)
```

For details see https://researchdatapod.com/how-to-solve-python-attributeerror-module-datetime-has-no-attribute-today/